# Adding Mean Bar To Vertical Scatter ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 to make vertical scatter charts using the following code and data. I would like to add a median bar to both Wk42 and Wk28. Sorry for the simple question this is my first weekend with R.

```
ggplot(test, aes(x=Week, y=Score, color=PTID)) + geom_point(shape=1)


    PTID    Week    Score
1   Subject 1   Wk42    NA
2   Subject 2   Wk42    0
3   Subject 3   Wk42    6
4   Subject 4   Wk42    NA
5   Subject 5   Wk42    NA
6   Subject 6   Wk42    78
7   Subject 7   Wk42    42
8   Subject 8   Wk42    NA
9   Subject 9   Wk42    38
10  Subject 10  Wk42    2
11  Subject 11  Wk42    4
12  Subject 12  Wk42    1
13  Subject 13  Wk42    NA
14  Subject 14  Wk42    NA
15  Subject 15  Wk42    17
16  Subject 1   Wk28    NA
17  Subject 2   Wk28    0
18  Subject 3   Wk28    11
19  Subject 4   Wk28    NA
20  Subject 5   Wk28    NA
21  Subject 6   Wk28    25
22  Subject 7   Wk28    28
23  Subject 8   Wk28    5
24  Subject 9   Wk28    33
25  Subject 10  Wk28    3
26  Subject 11  Wk28    0
27  Subject 12  Wk28    0
28  Subject 13  Wk28    NA
29  Subject 14  Wk28    NA
30  Subject 15  Wk28    11
```

Thanks!

Comment: edited the answer it should work now

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need to do facetting to add this. First you have to calculate median in both groups and create a `data.frame`. Then you can add lines using `geom_hline`.

```
library(dplyr)

data_hline <- data %>% group_by(Week) %>% summarize(Median = median(Score))

        ggplot(test, aes(x=Week, y=Score, color=PTID)) + geom_point(shape=1) +
    facet_wrap(~Week) + geom_hline(data=data_hline,aes(yintercept=Median))
```

Here is a reproducible example

```
data_hline <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarize(Median = median(mpg))
> ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl,y=mpg,fill=as.factor(gear))) + geom_point()+
+ facet_wrap(~cyl,scales="free_x")+ geom_hline(data=data_hline,aes(yintercept=Median))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use the `colour` parameter in `geom_point`, meaning that the data isn't already grouped by subject before you add any other layers.

```
ggplot(test, aes(x=Week, y=Score)) + geom_point(aes(colour = PTID), shape=1) +
stat_summary(aes(Week, Score), data = test, fun.data = "median_hilow", geom = "crossbar")
```

[image]

Comment: Edited to use the median, not the mean.